# Java initialization order error

Tags: java, static

I would like to ask why the following code causes error:

```
class A
{
    A()
    {
       statObj.x = 5; 
    }

    int x;
    static A statObj = new A();
}
```

I get ExceptionInInitializerError. I don't understand why. In this case static variable `statObj` will be initialized as the first one. So, if I am right, static object `statObj = new A()` will be create as the first one.

What is the order of creation and initialization of this internal static object? Isn't statObj.x default initialized by 0 value, before the internal static object constructor is called `statObj.A()` ?  If that ,why statObj.x behaves like it wasn't initialized (I fought it was default initialized by 0 value) ?

And one more why this problem only occurs in constructor and not in method ? The following code works fine:

```
        class A
        {
            A()
            {  
            }

            void met1()
            {
                statObj.x = 5; 
            }

            int x;
            static A statObj = new A();
        }


        public MainClass
        {
            public static void main(String[] arg)
            {
                A a = new A();
                a.statObj.met1();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you think it would work?

Answer (score 9):

Consider what happens. The following static initializer:

```
static A statObj = new A();
```

calls `A()`, which then tries to access `statObj`:

```
A() {
  statObj.x = 5; 
}
```

However, at this point `statObj` is not yet initialized and is therefore `null`. A `NullPointerException` is thrown, which then gets translated into an `ExceptionInInitializerError` (since the `NPE` has occurred in a static initializer).

The second example does not have this problem, since by the time you try to access `statObj`, it has been fully initialized.

Comment: No, `statObj` hasn't been assigned yet, it will be assigned after the constructor `A()` has completed.

Comment: Ok I understand  your explanation, but still don't uderstand the code behaviour. If create new object the order of creation is like this:
- find A.class file,
- initialization of static variables,
- **default initialzation of non static variables**,
- allocation memory for the object
- explicit initialization of non static variables,
- constructor execution 

So when we create `statObj`, shouldn't `statObj.x` be default initialize (by 0) before the `statObj` constructor is called ? If not, than why we can do something like this:
`class B
{
    int y;

    B()
    {
        y = 5;
    }
`
?

Comment: @IzaMarek: *shouldn't statObj.x be default initialize (by 0) before the statObj constructor is called*. Well, no. Before the constructor is called and finishes **there is no `statObj`** (i.e. the reference is `null`).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a NullPointerException, because you are trying to access the instance stored in the static field before that object has been created. This is happening because it only gets created after its constructor completes. But you are calling this from within the constructor.

The second code works fine, because there the constructor (which does nothing) has a chance to complete.

Again:

```
 static A statObj = new A();
```

`statObj` will be null until the constructor (`new A()`) completes.

> If create new object the order of creation is like this: - find A.class file, - initialization of static variables, - default initialzation of non static variables, - allocation memory for the object - explicit initialization of non static variables, - constructor execution

Well, the problem here is that during "initialization of static variables" you are calling the constructor that tries to use the same static variable, jumping a bit ahead in your sequence if you will.

> So when we create statObj, shouldn't statObj.x be default initialize (by 0) before the statObj constructor is called ?

Yes, but that is not the problem here. The problem here is that `statObj` itself is null before its constructor finishes.

> statObj.x = 5;

If you did `this.x`, it would work. But `statObj` is still null at the time.

Comment: Please check comment that I wrote to @NPE answer

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an object (statObj.x) before it has been created. Try this instead:

```
class A
{
    A()
    { 
    }

    int x;
    static A statObj = new A();

    static {
        statObj.x = 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you intialized a static with constructor that contain this static.

To finish properly construcor should have that static value. But to have that static value construcor must be finished first.